# Construct a sequence of Lebesgue integrable functions.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Im studying for my qualifying exam and I encounter this old problem:

Construct a sequence of integrable functions $f_n : [0, 1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that

a. $f_n$ converge to zero function on [0, 1] pointwise a.e.

b. for any continuous function $g : [0, 1]\to\mathbb{R}$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 gf_n = \int_0^1 g$

I defined the following sequence $f_n=2^n$ if $x \in (k/2^n, k/2^n + 1/2^{2n} )$ for all $k$,  $0\leq k \leq 2^n-1 $ ,

$\textbf{0}$ otherwise .

I was able to prove part a but have no idea how to prove part b. Any help I would appreciate also if there is another function that satisfies it I would appreciate also.

Comment: You have to use the continuity of $g$, so take small high blocks that are very close to each other, then the continuity of $g$ ensures that the value increased by $f_n$ is approximately the nearby values skipped by $f_n$.

Comment: Are you sure that it is possible? Because considering the dominated convergence theorem (assuming that you could bound $|f_n g|$ by an integrable function) you'd have 
$$\lim_n \int_0^1 gf_n = 0$$